# react JS error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS and I am building a currency converter but i seem to have encountered and error and don't know why its occuring.
when i change the currency from the select drop down i get the following error
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AED')"

I would like to know what is wrong with the code could some1 please help?

my APP.jsx code is

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CurrencyRow from './CurrencyRow';


var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("apikey", "API key here");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: myHeaders
};

const BASE_URL = `https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/latest`;




function App() {

  const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([]);
  const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = useState();
  const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState();
  const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState();
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);
  const [amountInFromCurrency, setAmountInFromCurrency] = useState(true);

  let toAmount, fromAmount
  if (amountInFromCurrency){
    fromAmount = amount
    toAmount = amount * exchangeRate
  } else{
    toAmount = amount
    fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate
  }


  useEffect(()=> {
    fetch(BASE_URL, requestOptions)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const firstCurrency = Object.keys(data.rates)[0]
      setCurrencyOptions([data.base, ...Object.keys(data.rates)])
      setFromCurrency(data.base);
      setToCurrency(firstCurrency);
      setExchangeRate(data.rates[firstCurrency])
    });
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(fromCurrency != null && toCurrency !== null){
      fetch(`${BASE_URL}?symbols=${toCurrency}&base=${fromCurrency}`,requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json)
      .then(data => setExchangeRate(data.rates[toCurrency]))
    }
  }, [fromCurrency, toCurrency])

  function handleFromAmountChange(e){
    setAmount(e.target.value)
    setAmountInFromCurrency(true)
  }
  function handleToAmountChange(e){
    setAmount(e.target.value)
    setAmountInFromCurrency(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
        <div>convert</div>
        <CurrencyRow
          currencyOptions = {currencyOptions}
          selectedCurrency = {fromCurrency}
          onChangeCurrency = {e => setFromCurrency(e.target.value)}
          onChangeAmount = {handleFromAmountChange}
          amount = {fromAmount}
          />
        <div>=</div>
        <CurrencyRow
          currencyOptions = {currencyOptions}
          selectedCurrency = {toCurrency}
          onChangeCurrency = {e => setToCurrency(e.target.value)}
          onChangeAmount = {handleToAmountChange}
          amount = {toAmount}
          />
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I made a component and here is the code for CurrencyRow

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CurrencyRow(props) {
  const {
    currencyOptions,
    selectedCurrency,
    onChangeCurrency,
    onChangeAmount,
    amount
  } = props
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" className="input" value={amount} onChange={onChangeAmount}/>
      <select value={selectedCurrency} onChange={onChangeCurrency}>
        {currencyOptions.map(options => (
          <option key={options} value={options}>{options}</option>
        ))}
        
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Always censor your API keys!!!!

Comment: The keys are still here, you should remove the post entirely and re ask

Comment: thank you for pointing it out, although I dont intend to use these key in a project since this is for learning purpose, I will make sure to censor them next time

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in calling res.json function. It was just a typo error.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(fromCurrency != null && toCurrency !== null){
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}?symbols=${toCurrency}&base=${fromCurrency}`,requestOptions)
    .then(res => res.json()) // res.json ==>> res.json() 
    .then(data => setExchangeRate(data.rates[toCurrency]))
  }
}, [fromCurrency, toCurrency])
```

Comment: thankyou for pointing this silly mistake of mine, i spent 6hrs finding the issue and still couldn't figure it out!